# All service calls from silverlight failing

Tags: silverlight, web-services, silverlight-4.0

I have a strange issue. All the webservice calls from silverlight application in my computer are failing. When I checked with fiddler, I can see that all the services are properly returning data. But the service calls in silverlight end up in the Communication Exception. The remote server returned an error: Not found.

I am using silverlight 4.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these calls returning large sets of data?  It's possible you have to increase settings in your web.Config to allow marshalling of larger data sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was really small. The disk space in C: drive of my machine was very low. Once some space got freed up, the issue got resolved. Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

are you calling remote or local services?  If you are calling remote services, it could be there is no cross-domain policy in place on the remote server.  try making a "normal" asp.net page or console app (etc.) that calls the service. If that is successfull, then this is probably the issue.  you would have to make a sort of "proxy" webservice locally that calls the remote one--unless it is your own webservice and you can place a clientaccesspolicy.xml in there.  [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/06/10/silverlight-services-cross-domain-404-not-found.aspx) is a really good article on the subject.

Comment: I am doing a remote service call. The service is working fine and the clientaccesspolicy is in place. The same application is working in all my other colleagues machines.

Comment: so its only on YOUR mahchine that its not working? that seems to me its some type of config issue, like your firewall or something

Comment: It shouldn't be firewall I guess, since I am able to get all the responses to be seen through fiddler.